# Are Shader Storage Buffer Objects the right tool to have persistent memory between shader loops?

Tags: opengl, glsl, buffer, shader

### Context

I have a fragment shader that processes a 2D image. Sometimes a pixel may be considered "invalid" (RGB value 0/0/0) for a few frame, while being valid the rest of the frames. This causes temporal noise as these pixels flicker.

I'd like to implement a sort of temporal filter where each rendering loop, each pixel is "shown" (RGB value not 0/0/0) if and only if this pixel was "valid" in the last X loops, where X might be 5, 10, etc. I figured if I could have an array of the same size as the image, I could set the element corresponding to a pixel to 0 when that pixel is invalid and increment it otherwise. And if the value is >= X, then the pixel can be displayed.

Image latency caused by the temporal filter is not an issue, but I want to minimize performance costs.

### The question

So that's the context. I'm looking for a mechanism that allows me reading and writing (uniforms are therefore out) between different rendering loops of the same fragment shader. Reading back the data from my OpenGL application is a plus but not necessary.

I came across [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object), would it fit my needs?

Are there other concerns I should be aware of? Performances? Coherency/memory barriers?

Comment: Is there a reason why whether a pixel is "valid" is part of the color, instead of side-channel information (like the alpha)?

Comment: Just the way the previous pipeline handles it. I agree that a zero RGB value seems like a valid value, but this is a depth map and we cannot have this value unless the point was missing. I assume that having this info in a different channel wouldn't change the overall question here.

Comment: My first thought was [image load/store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) which I bet you are already using for your image processing. It makes sense since your're dealing with pixels. I think SSBO could also work but you would probably need to calculate addresses yourself.

Comment: it sounds like each pixel is only accessed by one "instance" (invocation) of the shader so there is no coherency issue. Coherency problems occur when you want more than one instance of the shader to access the same piece of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, SSBOs are a suitable tool to have persistent memory between shader loops.**

As I couldn't find a reason why it wouldn't work, I implemented it and I was indeed able to have a SSBO as an array with each element mapped to a pixel in order to do temporal filtering on each pixels.

I had to do a few things to not have artifacts in the image:

- Use `GL_DYNAMIC_COPY` when binding the data with `glBufferData`.
- Set my SSBO as `volatile` in the shader.
- Use a barrier (`memoryBarrierBuffer();`) in my shader to separate the writing and reading of the SSBO.

As mentioned by @user253751 in a comment, I had to convert texture coordinates to index arrays.

I checked the performance costs of using the SSBO and they were negligible in my case: <0.1 ms for a 848x480 frame.